# i'm having this issue can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Just show your flutter doctor output.

Comment: i'm new i just started learning

Comment: can you tell me how to do that

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

i have also gone through this error once,
you have modified file from flutter source file,
just clean the changes you have made,
you can find it using git status in flutter directory which file you have modified,
or you can simply install new flutter